# r Language - Difftime function - Why do I get an error?

Tags: r, difftime

I have two different variables (ended_at, started_at) containing times in a chr data type in a dataframe called all_trips.

Data from all_trips.

```
           started_at            ended_at 
1 2019-01-01 00:04:37 2019-01-01 00:11:07          
2 2019-01-01 00:08:13 2019-01-01 00:15:34          
3 2019-01-01 00:13:23 2019-01-01 00:27:12          
4 2019-01-01 00:13:45 2019-01-01 00:43:28           
5 2019-01-01 00:14:52 2019-01-01 00:20:56          
6 2019-01-01 00:15:33 2019-01-01 00:19:09
```

When I run this code:

```
all_trips$ride_length <- difftime(all_trips$ended_at,all_trips$started_at)
```

I get this error.

```
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks.

I'm supposed to get the difference between the two times.  I tried changing the chr data type, but that didn't work.  Probably because I didn't do it correctly.....

Comment: Can you share part of your data? It might be easier to help that way.

Comment: difftime does work with characters as long as they are in the correct format as you have above. Unfortunately I am unable to reproduce your error

Comment: Onyambu,  Thanks for trying.  Could it be that I haven't loaded the correct library?  I installed tidyverse and loaded tidyverse, dplyr, lubridate.

Comment: `difftime` is included in the basic R install. This should have nothing to do with the tidyverse or lubridate.

Comment: I think I spotted the problem.  Most of the data is in YMD HMS format.  After further review, some of it is in DMY HMS format.

Comment: also, based on the example you gave, it is ambiguous if the data is YMD or YDM, though I'd be surprised if it's that

Comment: @SnakePlissken if that's the answer, write an answer and mark the question solved! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think I spotted the problem. Most of the data is in YMD HMS format. After further review, some of it is in DMY HMS format

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If this is the coursera case project I think it is, try deleting your files and data frames and the reloading the CSV files straight into your working directory and then re-run read.csv() to load with the new name and work from there.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).